# MD5 with ASCII Char

Tags: character-encoding, md5

I have a string

```
    wDevCopyright = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Copyright: %c 1995 by WIRELESS.dev, Corp Communications Inc., All rights reserved.",0xa9];
```

and to munge it I call

```
-(NSString *)getMD5:(NSString *)source
{

 const char *src = [source UTF8String];
 unsigned char result[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
 CC_MD5(src, strlen(src), result);

     return [NSString stringWithFormat:
   @"%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x",
   result[0], result[1], result[2], result[3], 
   result[4], result[5], result[6], result[7],
   result[8], result[9], result[10], result[11],
   result[12], result[13], result[14], result[15]
   ]; //ret;
}
```

because of 0xa9 *src = [source UTF8String] does not create a char that represents the string, thus returning a munge that is not comparable with other platforms.

I tried to encode the char with NSASCIIStringEncoding but it broke the code.

How do I call CC_MD5 with a string that has ASCII characters and get the same hash as in Java?

---

Update to code request:

Java

```
private static char[] kTestASCII = {
        169
        };

System.out.println("\n\n>>>>> msg## " + (char)0xa9 + " " + (char)169 + "\n  md5 " + md5(new String(kTestASCII), false) //unicode = false
```

Result >>>>> msg## \251 \251
  md5 a252c2c85a9e7756d5ba5da9949d57ed

ObjC

```
     char kTestASCII [] = {
            169
        };


NSString *testString = [NSString stringWithCString:kTestASCII encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@">>>> objC msg## int %d char %c md5: %@", 0xa9, 169, [self getMD5:testString]);
```

Result >>>> objC msg## int 169 char © md5: 9b759040321a408a5c7768b4511287a6

** As stated earlier - without the 0xa9 the hashes in Java and ObjC are the same.  I am trying to get the hash for 0xa9 the same in Java and ObjC

---

Java MD5 code

```
private static char[] kTestASCII = {
    169
    };

md5(new String(kTestASCII), false);

    /**
     * Compute the MD5 hash for the given String.
     * @param s the string to add to the digest
     * @param unicode true if the string is unciode, false for ascii strings
     */
    public synchronized final String md5(String value, boolean unicode)
    {
        MD5();
        MD5.update(value, unicode);
        return WUtilities.toHex(MD5.finish());

    }
    public synchronized void update(String s, boolean unicode)
{


    if (unicode)
    {
        char[] c = new char[s.length()];
        s.getChars(0, c.length, c, 0);
        update(c);
    }
    else
    {
        byte[] b = new byte[s.length()];
        s.getBytes(0, b.length, b, 0);
        update(b);
    }
}

public synchronized void update(byte[] b)
{
    update(b, 0, b.length);
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Add a byte sub-array to the digest.
 */
public synchronized void update(byte[] b, int offset, int length)
{
    for (int n = offset; n < offset + length; n++)
        update(b[n]);
}

/**
 * Add a byte to the digest.
 */
public synchronized void update(byte b)
{
    int index = (int)((count >>> 3) & 0x03f);
    count += 8;
    buffer[index] = b;
    if (index >= 63)
        transform();
}
```

I believe that my issue is with using NSData withEncoding as opposed to a C char[] or the Java byte[].  So what is the best way to roll my own bytes into a byte[] in objC?

Comment: Could you please state your question? We like seeing explicit questions here.

Comment: Thanks for guiding me to become a better list citizen.

Comment: What does your Java code look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to GBegan's explanation - here is my solution

```
for(int c = 0; c < [s length]; c++){
    int number = [s characterAtIndex:c];
    unsigned char c[1];
    c[0] = (unsigned char)number;
    NSMutableData *oneByte = [NSMutableData dataWithBytes:&c length:1];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The character you are having problems with, ©, is the Unicode [COPYRIGHT SIGN (00A9)](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0080.pdf). The correct UTF-8 encoding of this character is the byte sequence `0xc9 0xa9`.

You are attempting, however to convert from the single-byte sequence `0xa9` which is not a valid UTF-8 encoding of any character. See table 3-7 of http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode5.2.0/ch03.pdf#G7404 . Since this is not a valid UTF-8 byte sequence, `stringWithCString` is converting your input to the Unicode [REPLACEMENT_CHARACTER (FFFD)](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/UFFF0.pdf). When this character is then encoded back into UTF-8, it yields the byte sequence `0xef 0xbf 0xbd`. The MD5 of this sequence is 9b759040321a408a5c7768b4511287a6 as reported by your Objective-C example.

Your Java example yields an MD5 of a252c2c85a9e7756d5ba5da9949d57ed, which simple experimentation shows is the MD5 of the byte sequence `0xa9`, which I have already noted is not a valid UTF-8 representation of the desired character.

I think we need to see the implementation of the Java md5() method you are using. I suspect it is simply dropping the high bytes of every Unicode character to convert to a byte sequence for passing to the MessageDigest class. This does not match your Objective-C implementation where you are using a UTF-8 encoding.

Note: even if you fix your Objective-C implementation to match the encoding of your Java md5() method, your test will need some adjustment because you cannot use `stringWithCString` with the `NSUTF8StringEncoding` encoding to convert the byte sequence `0xa9` to an NSString.

**UPDATE**

Having now seen the Java implementation using the deprecated [getBytes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28int,%20int,%20byte%5b%5d,%20int%29) method, my recommendation is to change the Java implementation, if at all possible, to use a proper UTF-8 encoding.

I suspect, however, that your requirements are to match the current Java implementation, even if it is wrong. Therefore, I suggest you duplicate the bad behavior of Java's deprecated getBytes() method by using `NSString getCharacters:range:` to retrieve an array of `unichar`s, then manually create an array of bytes by taking the low byte of each unichar.

Comment: Thanks - this is what I've suspected.  I will add the Java code to post.

Answer (score 0):

`stringWithCString` requires a null terminated C-String. I don't think that `kTestASCII[]` is necessarily null terminated in your Objective-C code. Perhaps that is the cause of the difference.

Try:

```
char kTestASCII [] = {
            169,
            0
        };
```

Comment: Result with null terminator >>>> objC msg## int 169 char © md5: 9b759040321a408a5c7768b4511287a6 Same as earlier post.

Comment: Sorry that didn't help. It was just something that jumped out at me as a flaw, albeit an apparently benign one, in your Objective-C test code.